# Dr. Wells and Mirakuru in The Flash and Arrow Universe

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

I have just recently finished season 2 of the CW series Arrow. During the events, at some point of the season, team Arrow resort to STAR labs to generate the cure for Mirakuru (Japanese pronunciation of Miracle, very humorous), in order to stop Slade Wilson AKA Deathstroke.

This event was never mentioned in The Flash series, at least so far.
My question is related to Dr. Wells in particular. We now know about his true identity and motivations, but is there any valid reason Dr. Wells never attempted to use the Mirakuru to give himself some sort of boost? As far as I know this has been totally overlooked in the series, but were there any other sources talking about this particular point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr**: No, you didn't miss anything. Nothing is ever mentioned in either series about why Dr. Wells wasn't tempted by the Mirakuru -- either as a villain, or even just as a very curious scientist. (But, read on for some reasoned speculation)

---

Without a direct explanation on-screen, the best we can do is try to figure out what might have kept Dr. Wells away. I can think of three good reasons, any combination of which would explain his lack of interest in the drug:

### Nasty Side Effects

It's possible that Dr. Wells might be passingly familiar with Mirakuru from his "research". Given how extensively he studied the life and history of The Flash, who it seems is destined to form a Justice League w/ Green Arrow and others, he may have run across stories about Deathstroke and what happened to him. Even if he wasn't already aware of it, Felicity would certainly have warned Caitlin and Cisco how dangerous the drug is, and they would have told Dr. Wells the same.

Dr. Wells considers himself a very smart person, and prides himself on being able to outsmart everyone around him. He's probably not going to be very eager to take a drug that's going to compromise him mentally and emotionally, since that's completely counter to his usual style.

### Not Enough Sample

It's also possible that the sample Oliver provided wasn't big enough to both make a cure *and* use on a human subject. We already know that STAR Labs used the entire sample up in making the cure, though we don't know if they made any effort to keep any. From a forensic chemistry perspective, this probably meant putting portions of the sample through devices like mass spectrometers, which break down an unknown substance into known parts. These devices usually destroy the source sample in the process. (For example, a GC/MS vaporizes a substance and measures various aspect of the the constituent components.)

So, if there was only a small sample of the drug, and analyzing it destroyed it, there may not have been enough left to have any effect on someone. As part of his cover identity, Dr. Wells certainly wouldn't jeopardize his team's ability to formulate a cure, so he would have to let them destroy the sample.

### Better Things To Do

Over the course of the season, we've seen that Cisco and Caitlin occasionally do independent work at the labs. Dr. Wells usually finds out about these side projects through simple curiosity -- he sees them doing something and asks questions. Obviously, since they work for him, they can't actively keep this kind of project secret.

But remember, the showdown with Deathstroke was happening while Barry was still in a coma, and STAR Labs had just had a major catastrophe. Dr. Wells probably had many other issues to deal with, between the PR nightmare, trying to keep the lab operational, and trying to weasel his was into Barry's life.

The STAR Labs team may not have seen any reason to involve Wells in what they were doing, especially if they didn't think he would object and didn't need his assistance. They may simple have managed to work up the Mirakuru cure without Wells even knowing about it.

Comment: +1. Your first point was going to be my answer.  Mirakuru drives people nuts.  Aside from desperate down-and-outs like the people in the Glades, who WOULD want to try it?  Especially when you've already got your own special abilities giving you an edge.

Answer (score 9):

THe two other answers have a valid point. Here are other possible reasons that Dr. Wells didn't try the Mirakuru serum.

**That's not what happened in the original timeline**

Also, Wells wants more than anything that the events in his timeline happen. Consuming the Mirakuru may change the future. Difficult for a speedster with uncontrollable rage to keep things under control.

**The Mirakuru may have no effect on him**

The Flash has a different metabolism than normal humans. We can witness this in the first episode when alcohol, even super strong alcohol prepared by Caithleen, has no effect/limited effect on Barry. We don't know exactly how similar are the powers of Barry and Dr.Wells but we can expect that, when powered by the wheelchair, Dr. Wells has fast healing ability and fast metabolism. The mirakuru may have no effect/limited effect on speedster.

Comment: Both are excellent points.

Comment: #2 is a good point, though it's one of those things comics routinely get wrong about biology. Rapidly metabolizing drugs generally affects how long their effects last. Since Mirakuru's effects are permanent, a fast metabolism *shouldn't* make much difference. But in the DC universe, it probably would :)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield True, although it's well-established that speedsters also *heal* very quickly, and mirakuru use involves a lengthy first phase where the body reacts violently to its introduction (remember the bleeding eyes).  Even given true biology, I don't think it's a stretch to imagine that a speedster's body would "heal" from the mirakuru (which is to say reject the chemical and reverse its effects) before it took hold.

Answer (score 3):

If he was briefed on what Mirakuru was, he would avoid the stuff.  Team Arrow knows all about the side effects of Mirakuru, and they're pretty brutal.  Almost dying, hallucinating (which they might not actually know about during S2), and uncontrollable rage are pretty big downsides.  While it's possible that Wells' future tech could improve Mirakuru to get rid of these side effects, it seems unlikely, or this may have been offered up as a solution for Roy.

Wells has a straightforward plan for accomplishing his goals.  He needs access to the Speed Force, which he'll get from Flash.  Then Wells can return home.  The Mirakuru does not enable progress to that goal.  Wells is already more than capable of beating the Flash, so additional strength and regenerative capabilities do nothing for him.  So he has little need for the Mirakuru himself.  It is possible he could use it on another person, to create some super powered henchmen, but since there's a cure now, the Flash would easily depower said henchmen.

Answer (score 2):

An additional point: in most or all iterations of the DC Universe with Star Labs, it is not a monolithic organization: there are branches wherever it is convenient for the story line. So, Team Arrow may have used the Starling City Star Labs or some other location other then Central City. Dr. Wells may have had nothing to do with it. This, of course, is conditional on Central City not having been named specifically at that time.

Comment: The question is about the TV shows, and AFAIK, in the TV shows, it is never mentioned said that Star Labs expands beyond Central City, the particle accelerator and the small team we know in the show. Knowing Wells' plan, it is very unlikely to be the case. Also, *Arrow* characters tend to address directly to Barry and Oliver when they need help from Star Labs.

Comment: @Taladris All you say is true. I am merely pointing out that while there is no evidence that the Star Labs in this universe follows the pattern, the pattern exists. If the inconsistency re: Wells and the Mirakuru became an issue beyond the nitpicky, it is likely the pattern which the writers would fall back on.